# How to make videojs progress bar responsive to click/tap right-to-left?

Tags: javascript, css, video.js, right-to-left

I can get almost all of the [videojs player](http://www.videojs.com) (version 4.6.4) to play right-to-left. In the css,  `transform: scale(-1, 1)` flips the `.vjs-default-skin .vjs-control` and, with it, even the `.vjs-play-progress` bar loads RTL. **But** clicking on the `.vjs-slider` to advance or rewind the video works LTR. For example, with the `.vjs-play-progress` at half-way along the `.vjs-slider`, clicking `.vjs-slider` at the far left should move the playhead and the progress bar to the end of the video (if it were RTL). Instead the progress bar (and the video) returns to the start, which it would normally as LTR. Vice-versa, clicking near the RTL start (far right) moves the progress bar and video to the end (far left). Probably nothing can be done about that in the css, but maybe in video.js? Is it possible to set RTL there?

**The workaround, 28-29/10** - Tried making the progress bar unclickable, using this: https://github.com/rsadwick/videojs-disable-progress - OK on PCs but the result on mobiles (iPad, Samsung) was a native player overlay and the start button not working. Ditched that. Thanks to this [question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22562556/disable-mouse-interaction-on-videojs-scrubber)), the best solution was to add 'pointer-events: none'; in the css for `.vjs-slider`.

Comment: Media controls usually are not reversed for RTL languages. Both [Google's](https://material.google.com/usability/bidirectionality.html#bidirectionality-rtl-mirroring-guidelines) and [Apple's](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPInternational/SupportingRight-To-LeftLanguages/SupportingRight-To-LeftLanguages.html) UX guidelines say to not flip media controls.

Comment: Thanks for the refs. Yes, it's not done, but maybe it should be, to be coherent with RTL languages. Apple's guideline says don't flip media controls, then says not to flip "Images, unless they communicate a sense of direction, such as arrows". And Google's says "The guiding principle for RTL interfaces is that time moves from right to left." So...